# How to solve this problem, in package body?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to solve this problem, in package body?

function get_amount should return acc_amount for acc_id

function get_date should return acc_date for acc_id

How to do this with the functions

And where there are error in the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
    PROCEDURE add_new_account
        ( p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type)
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO account (acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
        VALUES (acc_seq.nextval, p_acc_id, p_acc_name, p_acc_amount, p_acc_date);
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
    END;
    PROCEDURE upd_account
        (
          p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE accounts
            SET acc_naziv  = p_acc_naziv
              , acc_amount = p_acc_amount
              , acc_date   = p_acc_date
        WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
    COMMIT;
    END;
    PROCEDURE del_accounts
        (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type)
    DELETE FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
    END;
    FUNCTION get_amount
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    return Number is res number;
    begin 
        select acc_amount into res 
        from  account where acc_id =p_acc_id; 
        return res;
    end;
    FUNCTION get_date
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    RETURN date IS res1 date;
    BEGIN
        SELECT acc_date INTO res1
        FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
        RETURN res1;
        end;
   end account_api;
     /
```

Comment: Whats's your question? Which problem? could you explain a bit more?

Comment: *where there are error in the code?* Compilation errors are where the compiler indicates them (or somewhere before that, if the error is something like a missing closing quote, so the compiler doesn't fail until the next opening quote or the end of the package). Runtime errors will depend on what it's supposed to do and what data you have.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you need to decide the table name `accounts` or
  `account`. I supposed as `accounts` for edited code block that will
  appear below.
- For `PROCEDURE add_new_account` the number of arguments for values
  list is more than the number of arguments for column names' list.
- For `PROCEDURE upd_account`, there's no identifier defined as
  `p_acc_naziv` stated in the UPDATE statement.
- For `PROCEDURE del_accounts` `IS BEGIN` part is missing

There should be a `package header` before `package body` as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE account_api AS
    PROCEDURE add_new_account
        ( p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type);

    PROCEDURE upd_account
        (
          p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
    );
    PROCEDURE del_accounts
        (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type);

    FUNCTION get_amount
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    return Number;
    FUNCTION get_date
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    RETURN date;
end account_api;
```

and the `package body` should be as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
    PROCEDURE add_new_account
        ( p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type)
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO accounts(acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
        VALUES (-- acc_seq.nextval, --> need to be removed
                p_acc_id, p_acc_name, p_acc_amount, p_acc_date);
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
    END;
    PROCEDURE upd_account
        (
          p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
        , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
        , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE accounts
            SET /*acc_naziv  = p_acc_naziv  -->  there's no identifier defined as p_acc_naziv
                                            -->> suppose you'd use "acc_name = p_acc_name" here.  
              , */acc_amount = p_acc_amount
              , acc_date   = p_acc_date
        WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
    COMMIT;
    END;
    PROCEDURE del_accounts
        (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type)
    IS     -->  missing
    BEGIN  -->  missing
    DELETE FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
    COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
    END;
    FUNCTION get_amount
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    return Number is res number;
    begin
        select acc_amount into res
        from  accounts where acc_id =p_acc_id;
        return res;
    end;
    FUNCTION get_date
        (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
    RETURN date IS res1 date;
    BEGIN
        SELECT acc_date INTO res1
        FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
        RETURN res1;
        end;
   end account_api;
```